# Merge Model and its Relationship with result like join query in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I'm new at Laravel and Programming at that. I have a problem joining model with its relationship, here is what my model:

```
class MainClass extends Model
{
  public function first()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(First::class);
  }
  public function second()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Second::class);
  }
  public function third()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Third::class);
  }
}
```

When i try to get MainClass records then load it's relationship like:

```
$main = Main::where('status', 'ready')->get()
$main->load(['first','second'])
```

**Here's what i got:**

```
[{
"id":"1",
"name":"First Person",
"status": "ready",
"first":[
         {"main_id": "1", "prop":"One"},
         {"main_id":"1", "prop":"Two"}],
"second":[
         {"main_id": "1", "other":"Yes"},
         {"main_id":"1", "other":"Two"},
         {"main_id":"1", "other":"Three"}]
},{
"id":"5",
"name":"Fifth Person",
"status": "ready",
"first":[
         {"main_id": "5", "prop":"Five"},
         {"main_id":"5", "prop":"Six"}],
"second":[
         {"main_id": "5", "other":"Laptop"},
        {"main_id":"5", "other":"Pc"}]
}]
```

How can i merge that relationship so the result will be like join query,
**this is what i want:**

```
[{
"id":"1",
"name":"First Person",
"status": "ready",
"prop":"One",
"other:"Yes"
},{
"id":"1",
"name":"First Person",
"status": "ready",
"prop":"Two",
"other":"Two"
}]
```

I know there is a way to combine collection with merge or push in laravel, but i can't seem to get it right.

As of why not using join query, because i want to load relationship dynamically, so relation is not always loaded, but sometime they do. While join query, i have to write it manually (as far as i know) :-)

Maybe someone can point me somewhere, or maybe there is a package for something like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use eager loading, fetching the collection, then run groupBy, then the each, then the map function to return the results formatted as your wish.

Why not just simply run the joins

Comment: I understand about map function, but can u explain what should i groupBy, i'm still newbie about this.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with join;

```
$main = Main::query()->select(['main.id', 'main.name', 'main.status', 'f.prop', 's.other', 't.blabla'])
->leftJoin('first as f', 'f.main_id', 'main.id')
->leftJoin('second as s', 's.main_id', 'main.id')
->leftJoin('third as t', 't.main_id', 'main.id')
->where('main.status', 'ready')
->get();
```

Comment: I know about join, that is why my question is like join query.. :-)
So, there is no other way without join query to get result as i expected?